# My player rotation influnce my movement joystick how i fix this?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I crate a joystick and I calculate the direction the joystick make then with my direction I calculate my angle when I calculate my angle I duplicate my script so now one joystick for moving in script one and one joystick are for rotation in script 2, my problem is that when I rotate my player, let's say 90 degrees my move joystick moves the player to a different direction

The move joystick code have the angle calculate

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using Unity.Mathematics;
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEditor.Experimental.GraphView;
using UnityEngine;

public class joystick : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform player;
    public float speed;
    private bool touchStart = false;
    private Vector2 pointA;
    private Vector2 pointB;
    public Transform circle;
    public Transform outerCircle;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        Debug.Log(Input.mousePosition.x);

        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            if (Input.mousePosition.x < Screen.width / 2)
            {
                pointA = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(Input.mousePosition.x, Input.mousePosition.y, Camera.main.transform.position.z));
                circle.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().enabled = true;
                outerCircle.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().enabled = true;

                circle.transform.position = pointA;
                outerCircle.transform.position = pointA;
            }
        }

        if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
        {
            if (Input.mousePosition.x < Screen.width / 2)
            {
                pointB = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(Input.mousePosition.x, Input.mousePosition.y, Camera.main.transform.position.z));
                touchStart = true;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            touchStart = false;
            circle.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().enabled = false;
            outerCircle.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().enabled = false;
        }
    }

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        if (touchStart)
        {
            if (Input.mousePosition.x < Screen.width/2)
            {
                Vector2 offset = pointB - pointA;
                Vector2 direction = Vector3.ClampMagnitude(offset, 1.0f);
                float angle = Mathf.Atan2(direction.y, direction.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg - 90;
                Quaternion angleAxis = Quaternion.AngleAxis(angle, Vector3.forward);
                movePlayer(direction);
                circle.transform.position = new Vector2(pointA.x + direction.x, pointA.y + direction.y);
            }
        }
    }

    void movePlayer(Vector2 direction)
    {
        player.Translate(direction + player.rotation) * speed * Time.deltaTime);  
    }
}
```